# Xamarin.Forms: Error in creating a Chart using OxyPlot

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Good Day Everyone. I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Application and I want to create a Chart using OxyPlot. I have tried this code but it has an error that points to my 
**LoadApplication(new App());** MainActivity.cs in my Xamarin.Android part stating that

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object"

What do you think is the reason behind this?

These are some of the codes I have:

**SalesPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.SalesPage"
         xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.XamarinForms;assembly=OxyPlot.XamarinForms"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="Sales Page">

 <StackLayout>
   <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding OxyPlotModel}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**SalesPage.xaml**

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;   
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
{
    public partial class SalesPage 
    {


    public SalesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "OxyPlot Demo" };

        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });

        var series1 = new LineSeries
        {
            MarkerType = OxyPlot.MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 4,
            MarkerStroke = OxyPlot.OxyColors.White
        };

        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.0, 6.0));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.4, 2.1));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2.0, 4.2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3.3, 2.3));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.7, 7.4));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6.0, 6.2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8.9, 8.9));

        plotModel.Series.Add(series1);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;



using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Droid;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "XamarinFormsDemo", Icon = "@drawable/recordsicon",     MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize |     ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity :     global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
       ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the DataContext for the page anywhere. At least not in the code that you are showing. Hence, the binding to the `OxyPlotModel` property, which also doesn't seem to exist, will not work.

If you want a quick and dirty fix just to see the model you have made in your page, then simply assign it to the `PlotView` like so:

1. Add a name attribute to your plotview. `x:Name="Graph"`
2. Simply assign the created PlotModel to the Model property of `Graph`: `Graph.Model = plotModel`.

However, you might need to do that in an `OnAppearing` override, so your code might need to be moved down in that method like:

```
public override void OnAppearing()
{
    var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "OxyPlot Demo" };

    plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
    plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });

    var series1 = new LineSeries
    {
        MarkerType = OxyPlot.MarkerType.Circle,
        MarkerSize = 4,
        MarkerStroke = OxyPlot.OxyColors.White
    };

    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.0, 6.0));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.4, 2.1));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2.0, 4.2));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3.3, 2.3));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.7, 7.4));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6.0, 6.2));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8.9, 8.9));

    plotModel.Series.Add(series1);
    Graph.Model = plotModel;
}
```

A better way to do this is to utilize the MVVM pattern, by creating a ViewModel like so:

```
public class SalesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PlotModel _plotModel;

    public PlotModel PlotModel
    {
        get { return _plotModel; }
        set {
            _plotModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // other methods here that create your model

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate your ViewModel somewhere, probably in OnAppearing() and set it as BindingContext:

```
public override void OnAppearing()
{
    var viewModel = new SalesViewModel();
    this.BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

Then you can use that binding you created in your Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.SalesPage"
    xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.XamarinForms;assembly=OxyPlot.XamarinForms"
    BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
    Title="Sales Page">

    <StackLayout>
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding PlotModel}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Remember to call `RaisePropertyChanged()` on your `PlotModel` every time you change it to get it reflected in the View: `RaisePropertyChanged("PlotModel");`

Comment: Exactly Sir, I don't know where's the PlotModel in the codes I have copied. However, I think following your codes might lead to success? Can I just break it down? First, where should I copy your code in the OnAppearing override? Second, do I need to create a ViewModel? Third, how will I instantiate the ViewModel in my OnAppearing override? Last is, what should I put inside my .XAML file? Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Alright Sir. I'm just kinda confuse because I think the codes are incomplete. If you don't mind, can you please tell me what to do first and the next steps? Should I start coding the XAML and then what? Thanks a lot Sir. More powers to you

Comment: The code is incomplete because you have to use your own brain and fill in the rest. No one is going to give you a complete copy/paste solution that will drop in perfectly into your code and just work straight out of the box. I've given you a perfectly good sample that shows two different ways to approach this. If you can't figure out how to use this code, be smart about it and describe _exactly_ what you have tried, what went wrong. I can't guess what you have tried to do with the example that was provided.

Comment: Noted Sir. Sorry. Thanks for your help anyway. God bless.